# What's the name of the html doc style which has 2 columns?

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, momentjs

Here are 2 sites using this 2 columns style which I can't tell a name:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html

http://momentjs.com/docs/

They're beautiful and I want to know the name of this kind of style and is there any template/tool to create this kind of document? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of that style's name, but I think that what you are looking for are styles that stretches to full windows size. Try searching for Liquid CSS, what it does is using full page width and percentages instead of putting all into a less than 1024px wrapping.